# How to find thevenin's eq circuit from the given figure?

Tags: thevenin

[image]

So I started with finding Rth shorting all voltage sources and opening all current sources getting at 10||5 case getting it as 10/3 = 3.33 ohms. After that using source transformation I changed the given 3A current source to a voltage of 12V.
That brings me to this point Can anybody tell me how to proceed further ?

Comment: Questions with no attempt at a solution are closed.

Comment: The interior becomes 18v + 12v (be careful with polarities) in series with 4 + 6 ohms. This becomes 30v in series with 10 ohms. Convert to Norton: 3 amps in parallel with 10 ohms. Notice a reversal of that 3 amps would reverse the polarity across the 4 ohms, and the model would be +18v -12v, in series with 4+6 ohms, or 6 volts in series with 10 ohms, and the Norton model would be 0.6 amps in parallel with 10 ohms. Again, you must be consistent with assigning polarities; this comes from practice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a homework question with no attempt shown at solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit is very simple to understand.

step 1:
convert 10 v in series with a 5 ohm resistance to a current source.
you will get 2 A (10/2) current source in parellel with 5 ohm resistance.the polarity of this 2 A is opposite to the current source in first branch.

the two current source thus cancels each other.

step 2.

convert 3A current source to a voltage source.

Now you have only 2 branches:

1. 30 v (18+12)  with 10 ohm in series.
2. a 5 ohm resistance.

Now i think you can find easily.
Hope this helps!